# Commenting about usage of MathJax while reviewing answers and questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, review

While posting questions or answers for the first time many beginner users do not use MathJax. Of course, others can edit the questions or answers to improve the MathJax but I feel that it is better to inform about MathJax to the beginners. While reviewing answers I observed that there are three options

1. Looks Ok
2. Edit
3. Recommend deletion

In the 'Recommend deletion' section there is an option to leave comments about various causes such as 'this is a link only answer' and other options. Likewise, I felt that there should be an option to comment about the usage of MathJax which includes a quick reference of MathJax tutorial such as [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) page. Isn't it possible or am I missing something?

**Note:**
I do not mean that we should delete posts that lack MathJax formatting. In such cases, we should leave appropriate comments about the usage of MathJax. What is my point that there should be a prewritten comment which should be available to reviewers.

Comment: Are you suggesting this as an additional comment for the “Recommend deletion” option or as a fourth review resolution? The former would imply that not using MathJax is a reason to delete the question.

Comment: @Martin R  I think not knowing MathJax should not be a reason to delete the post

Comment: When you recommend deletion, you are asserting that a post is not salvageable.  If the only problem with the post is that it lacks proper formatting, then I would draw the conclusion that the post *is* salvageable.  Hitting "edit" or leaving a comment would be more appropriate.

Comment: @ Xander Henderson, I am very sorry if my phrases imply that we should delete the posts which lack MathJax. I only meant that instead of leaving comments by ourselves, there should be an option to leave comments like that we have in the deletion section.